# With the ReportViewer Control for SQL Server Reporting Services, can I change the subreport programatically in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, .net-3.5, ssrs-2008

Currently we have a report with multiple sub-reports that could be used.  Up until now we've been changing the subreports manually every time we want to print something different.  However I'm trying to build a C# Winforms app with the ReportViewer control that could change the subreports out dynamically.  Is this possible in any way?  This is for SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Framework if this helps any.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial [here](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/subreports/index.html) (http://www.gotreportviewer.com/subreports/index.html) Give a try.